# Taking part from array of numbers by percent

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting

Let's have example of array full of numbers greater than 0:

```
let prices = [10,6200,20,20,350,900,26,78,888,10000,78,15000,200,1280,2000,450];
```

After we add all the numbers and get total amount (in example it is `33770`) we want take some % (part) from this total amount. Let's say 5% (`1689`).

Our output will be array of best candidates from first array. Of course, the value does not have to be exactly 5%, but it **cannot be more than 5%**, and it must contain numbers **as large as possible.**

I tried to make some algorithm but it was unpredictable and very inaccurate.

EDIT: I got idea to use The Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion. Can help this?

Comment: Show the algorithm as you tried it. Ask why its unpredictable.

Comment: *Our output will be array of best candidates from first array?* What does it mean?

Comment: what result do you expect with the actual values?

Comment: @Ele array of numbers from first array witch will have together value of 10% of first array

Comment: @Baterka values lesser or equal to 10% of 33770?

Comment: First sum the array.  Then calculate the total and 10%.  Then you will want to sort the array, smallest to largest, then accumulate the total until it is less than but not over 10%, in your example 3377.

Comment: @Ele Equal or little less, but nor greater

Comment: @KeithAymar yes this was my algorithm, bur I dont want to take numbers just from lowest to highest possible. I want to make actual best combination.

Comment: "best combination"  you have to define what "best" is

Comment: @KeithAymar Better than ASC from lower to highest

Comment: Are you looking for a packing algorithm?

Comment: meaning?  the least count of numbers to make up the total?

Comment: Also search for "knapsack problem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could either add the element at the index to a temporary array, or not. Then, check for *if the index reaches the array length* or *if the sum is greater than the wanted sum*. Then, either check the sum and add the temp array to the result set, or not. Finally, proceed until all indices are visited.

```js
function getCombinations(array, sum) {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

    function fork(i, t) {
        var r = (result[0] || []).reduce(add, 0),
            s = t.reduce(add, 0);
        if (i === array.length || s > sum) {
            if (s <= sum && t.length && r <= s) {
                if (r < s) {
                    result = [];
                }
                result.push(t);
            }
            return;
        }
        fork(i + 1, t.concat([array[i]]));
        fork(i + 1, t);
    }

    var result = [];
    fork(0, []);
    return result;
}

var result = getCombinations([10, 6200, 20, 20, 350, 900, 26, 78, 888, 10000, 78, 15000, 200], 1689)

console.log(result[0].reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is very good. Its little magic for me but I will make it trough sometimes to understand it :D Thanks I think this is right answer. Just maybe add to code that it will take as winner the result with lowest amount of items

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functions `reduce` and `sort` to get the highest values.

```js
let prices = [10,6200,20,20,350,900,26,78,888,10000,78,15000,200],
    percentage = .05;
    total = prices.reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0),
    sorted = prices.sort((a, b) => b - a),
    {result} = sorted.reduce((a, n) => {
      if ((a.sum + n) <= (total * percentage)) {
        a.sum += n;
        a.result.push(n)
      }
      return a;
    }, {sum: 0, result: []});


console.log(`Lesser than ${(total * percentage)}: `, result.reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0) <= (total * percentage));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: He changed it to 5%.  can you modify your answer.  I want to see it run.

Comment: Repeated values are not problem.. Bigger problem is that I dont want to go from lowest to highest. I want to make it smarter than just taking lowest values and go up

Comment: This guy is probably looking for a one dimensional bin packing problem.

Comment: Knapsack problem actually.